# Resize an image in php with max height and width

Tags: php, image

Ok so I'm trying to resize an image using php.  I do not have access to install plugins on the server I use at this time.

`$originalimage` is the actual original image that I'm going to resize.
`$width` is another parameter to define `$original_width`. The same can be said for `$height` and `$original_height`.

```
$original_width = imagesx($originalimage);
$original_height = imagesy($originalimage);

$max_width = $thumbwidth;
$max_height = $thumbheight;

$width = $original_width;
$height = $original_height;
```

Using the pre-setup above I start to work on this one here. This works but no way to set a max height. For example I pass a max width as `$thumbwidth` and max height as `$thumbheight` and this will work as desired till I then try to go ahead and use an image that's higher than it is wide. (Portrait image.)  It does not completely fail however it does fail to enforce a max height, rendering an image that can potentially be very high.

```
if ($width > $height) {
$newwidth = $thumbwidth;
$divisor = $width / $thumbwidth;
$newheight = floor( $height / $divisor);
} else {
$newheight = $thumbheight;
$divisor = $height / $thumbheight;
$newwidth = floor( $width / $divisor );
}
$image = imagecreatetruecolor( $newwidth, $newheight );
imagecopyresampled( $image, $originalimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $original_width, $original_height );
```

After trying to understand this and failing after a few hours I came up with the code below which I had gotten from php.net.    As you can see there was a reason I set two sets of variables equal to each other in the pre-setup part of the code.   Mostly because I can not comprehend calling `$max_width` as `$thumbwidth` in the second code segment.
This below works as well until you pass in a parameter though that is larger than the width or height of `$originalimage`.

```
# taller
if ($height > $max_height) {
    $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
    $height = $max_height;
}

# wider
if ($width > $max_width) {
    $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
    $width = $max_width;
}


$image = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
imagecopyresampled( $image, $originalimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $original_width, $original_height );
```

I'm sorry I can't find a way to do this on my own.  As for this being a duplicate question, Most similar questions end up with "[Insert plugin name here] is better use that instead."  I am asking specifically for an answer that does not use other plugins or javascript. (Besides GD which is pre-installed on my server.)
Before I end this question I will say that I am using `imagejpeg($image);` so the use of HTML or CSS is completely forbidden.

Comment: use white hat's php resizing script it works like a dream

Comment: I've looked at it just now, As good as that may be I need it to be... Like the examples above.  I'm not looking to use any file includes or functions just yet.  I'm trying to make my script run linear without having to rely on other files.  I've seen the functions in white hat's php resizing script and it doesn't seem like I can just pull them out of it and use them on their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a class I whipped up for a program I worked on. maybe it will help you?

```
<?php
class ImageHelper
{
    /**
     * @static
     * @param $source string Path for source image
     * @param $destination string Path for destination image to be placed
     * @param $targetWidth int Width of the new image (in pixels)
     * @param $targetHeight int Height of the new image (in pixels)
     * @param $strict bool
     */
    public static function createImage($source, $destination, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $strict = false){
        $dir = dirname($destination);
        if(!is_dir($dir)){
            mkdir($dir, 0770, true);
        }
        $fileContents = file_get_contents($source);
        $image = imagecreatefromstring($fileContents);

        $thumbnail = ImageHelper::resizeImage($image, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $strict);
        imagejpeg($thumbnail, $destination, 100);
        imagedestroy($thumbnail);
        imagedestroy($image);
    }

    /**
     * Resize an image to the specified dimensions
     * @param string $original Path to the original image
     * @param int $targetWidth Width of the new image (in pixels)
     * @param int $targetHeight Height of the new image (in pixels)
     * @param bool $strict True to crop the picture to the specified dimensions, false for best fit
     * @return bool|resource Returns the new image resource or false if the image was not resized.
     */
    public static function resizeImage($original, $targetWidth, $targetHeight, $strict = false)
    {
        $originalWidth = imagesx($original);
        $originalHeight = imagesy($original);

        $widthRatio = $targetWidth / $originalWidth;
        $heightRatio = $targetHeight / $originalHeight;

        if(($widthRatio > 1 || $heightRatio > 1) && !$strict){
            // don't scale up an image if either targets are greater than the original sizes and we aren't using a strict parameter
            $dstHeight = $originalHeight;
            $dstWidth = $originalWidth;
            $srcHeight = $originalHeight;
            $srcWidth = $originalWidth;
            $srcX = 0;
            $srcY = 0;
        }elseif ($widthRatio > $heightRatio) {
            // width is the constraining factor
            if ($strict) {
                $dstHeight = $targetHeight;
                $dstWidth = $targetWidth;
                $srcHeight = $originalHeight;
                $srcWidth = $heightRatio * $targetWidth;
                $srcX = floor(($originalWidth - $srcWidth) / 2);
                $srcY = 0;
            } else {
                $dstHeight = ($originalHeight * $targetWidth) / $originalWidth;
                $dstWidth = $targetWidth;
                $srcHeight = $originalHeight;
                $srcWidth = $originalWidth;
                $srcX = 0;
                $srcY = 0;
            }
        } else {
            // height is the constraining factor
            if ($strict) {
                $dstHeight = $targetHeight;
                $dstWidth = $targetWidth;
                $srcHeight = $widthRatio * $targetHeight;
                $srcWidth = $originalWidth;
                $srcY = floor(($originalHeight - $srcHeight) / 2);
                $srcX = 0;
            } else {
                $dstHeight = $targetHeight;
                $dstWidth = ($originalWidth * $targetHeight) / $originalHeight;
                $srcHeight = $originalHeight;
                $srcWidth = $originalWidth;
                $srcX = 0;
                $srcY = 0;
            }
        }

        $new = imagecreatetruecolor($dstWidth, $dstHeight);
        if ($new === false) {
            return false;
        }

        imagecopyresampled($new, $original, 0, 0, $srcX, $srcY, $dstWidth, $dstHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

        return $new;
    }

}
```

Comment: Even though this was not my overall choice to use, looking at this helped me greatly in my understanding of image re-sizing in general. Enough so that I wrote my own unique algorithm to determine what should be re-sized.  (Base it on height or base it on width? issue)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar problem building the thumbs for a gallery page.  I tried Daniel Nyamasyo solution above but just could not get past the "$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($sourcefile);" line without getting "Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" no matter what $sourcefile I fed it.
I came up with this dirty method.

```
    <?php
    // Some variables
    $thumb_width = 162; // The maximum values you want
    $thumb_height = 122;
    $thumb_pointer = 'thumbs';  // Put your output folder here which must exist

    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $image_name);
    $width = imagesx( $img );
    $height = imagesy( $img );
    if ($width>=$height)
    {
        // Now calculate thumbnail size
        $new_width = $thumb_width;
        $new_height = floor( $height * ($thumb_width / $width));
        // The 'dirty' bit I found was needed for square or near square images      
        while ($new_height > $thumb_height)
        {
            $new_width = floor($new_width * 0.99);
            $new_height = floor($new_height * 0.99);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $new_height = $thumb_height;
        $new_width =  floor($width * ($thumb_height / $height));
    }
    // Create a new temporary image 
    $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
    // Copy and resize old image into new image 
    imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
    // Save the thumbnail into a file   
    imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $thumb_pointer.'/'.$image_name);
?>
```